# Netbeans intellisense not working for children classes

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, intellisense

So I have Model class:

```
class Model {
    protected $database = null;

    protected function __construct() {
        $this->database = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST, 
                DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $this->database-> //Here intellisense works
    }
}
```

And I also have class that extends it

```
class Queries extends Model {
    ...
    public function example(){
        $this->database-> //Here intellisense doesn't works
    }
    ...
}
```

Why intellisense doesn't work for Queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add comment in your parent class :

```
class Model {
    /**
     * @var PDO $database
     */
    protected $database = null;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, it's a better way in your case. Commenting class is very important for the IDE and completion.